# create distinct array set from multidimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, distinct

I have been trying to create a distinct array of country code that will take all date which is for only that country and add inside that array using a multi dimensional array in PHP but I am unable to archive.

#### Input Array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2019-01-01
            [1] => lt
            [2] => passport
            [3] => 30122719
            [4] => 2019-03-01
            [5] => 357717289
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2019-01-01
            [1] => pl
            [2] => identity_card
            [3] => 9879386836
            [4] => 2018-11-01
            [5] => 643023760
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2019-01-02
            [1] => lt
            [2] => passport
            [3] => 46530663
            [4] => 2019-03-01
            [5] => 357717289
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2019-01-02
            [1] => pl
            [2] => identity_card
            [3] => 4531480055
            [4] => 2017-10-21
            [5] => 324444899
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2019-01-03
            [1] => lt
            [2] => passport
            [3] => 54163812
            [4] => 2019-03-01
            [5] => 357717289
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2019-01-03
            [1] => fr
            [2] => drivers_license
            [3] => 95180604
            [4] => 2018-07-02
            [5] => 942959784
        )
)
```

#### Expected output

```
Array
(
    [lt] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2019-03-01
            [1] => 2019-03-01
            [2] => 2019-03-01
        )

    [pl] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2018-11-01
            [1] => 2017-10-21
        )

    [fr] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2018-07-02
        )

)
```

So far I have tried the following

```
$dist = array();
foreach ($inputArray as $key => $value) {
     foreach ($value as $index => $v) {
          $dist[$value[1]] = $value[4];
     }
}
```

An the code returns the following

```
Array
(
    [lt] => 2019-03-01
    [pl] => 2016-08-01
    [fr] => 2019-04-01
    [de] => 2009-01-01
    [uk] => 2015-09-07
    [es] => 2015-09-08
    [it] => 2019-02-16
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close - you just miss the `[]` operator which append element to array.

See this:

```
$dist = array();
$cc = array('fr', 'pl', 'lt');
foreach ($inputArray as $key => $val) {
     if (in_array($val[1], $cc) { //get only the county code you want
          $dist[$val[1]][] = $val[4]; // notice the change in this line
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @dWinder for your answer, however I also achieved this result but didn't understand how to apply condition to keep for only specific country code date and achieve my final expected output

Comment: Added `if` condition. Notice your example input has only those 3 country code